# How to install a Python project from the subdirectory of a git repository with pip?

Tags: git, pip

I am trying to install *Deribit* (a crypto-currency exchange) Python client (in my Amazon Sagemaker Notebook).

The project can be found in the `python` subdirectory of a git repository at the following location:

- https://github.com/deribit/deribit-api-clients/tree/master/python

How can I install this project from this location with *pip*?

Comment: `deribit/deribit-api-clients`

Comment: @h4z3: I have tried this: !pip install git+https://github.com/deribit/deribit-api-clients.git

Error I get:

Collecting git+https://github.com/deribit/deribit-api-clients.git

    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-req-build-fddoazjs/setup.py

Answer (score 8):

As noted in the ["*VCS Support*" chapter of *pip*'s documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/), the correct notations are the following:

- `python -m pip install 'openapi-client @ git+https://github.com/deribit/deribit-api-clients.git#subdirectory=python'`
- `python -m pip install 'git+https://github.com/deribit/deribit-api-clients.git#egg=openapi-client&subdirectory=python'`

The first one being the modern notation, and the second one being a rather outdated notation.

***Notes***:

- use the `git+https` scheme
- specify the subdirectory where the project can be found inside the git repository `subdirectory=path/to/project`
- specify the name of the actual Python project:

  - either in the form `ProjectName @ vcs+protocol://...`, which is the modern notation
  - or as a fragment `egg=ProjectName` of the VCS URI, which is the outdated notation

Comment: This should be marked as solved with this answer :)

Answer (score -2):

So when you pip install it essentially you are downloading the git repo from the website onto your own git repo. For example (not trying to self promote or anything) but here is what one of my git repos looks like: https://github.com/lxa215/Shifaa-EMR-System.git

The username is your github username. The repo name is the custom repo that you provide.

Hope this helps!

Also you can just clone it since it’s public!

Yeah just enter git clone “......” (repo name from GitHub) in your terminal.